# How to show or hide element based on Geo ip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script to give me the Geo Location, like "CA" or "US". I want to show a specific into in my html base on the user location. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```html
<div id="ip">Loading...</div>
<div id="country_code"></div>
<div id="country_code">Hello Canada</div>
<div id="country_code">Hello USA</div>


<script>
    $.get("https://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
        $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
        $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    }, "jsonp");
    document.getElementById("US").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("CA").style.display = "block";
</script>
```

CSS:

```css
#US { text-align: left; color: blue; display:none;} 
#CA { text-align: left; color: blue; display:none;}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/1223/)

Comment: You can use a simple if condition...  `if(response.country_code=='US'){//Do something here}`

Comment: And IDs should be unique within a page

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks, that sorta worked, It shows up for USA, but not if I change the order. USA: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndfmcLcc/3/)  CA:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndfmcLcc/2/)  World:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndfmcLcc/5/)  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Groc I have posted an answer below. You can run the snippet. All should work just fine :) You do need to add the div's as shown in my answer for #CA and #US.

Comment: @Groc If my post does answer your question, please remember to mark it. This will help others with the same question find the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As commented, a simple if condition will work.

```js
$.get("https://freegeoip.app/json/", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
    if(response.country_code=='CA'||response.country_code=='US'){
     document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
 }
}, "jsonp");
```

```css
#US { text-align: left; color: blue; display:none;} 
#CA { text-align: left; color: blue; display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ip">Loading...</div>
<div id="country_code"></div>
<div id="CA">THE CA</div>
<div id="US">THE US</div>
```

> **UPDATE: 15/12/2018**

**http://freegeoip.net** Has shutdown. I have updated the url with **https://freegeoip.app**

---

If you have any questions, leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks again :) I also added a bit to include "Hello World" [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/1230/)

Comment: Should this be a separate question: How do I include an array for Europe in the JS code above, check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/1233/) Any suggestions?

Comment: I posted it as a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175630/how-to-show-or-hide-element-based-on-an-array-of-geo-ip)

Comment: Yes that would need to be submitted as a new question, I will look at the other question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can decorate your elements with the country codes, then use `getElementsByClassName` to toggle. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbnxnt1a/1/).

Updated your sample:

HTML

```
<div class="hide CA">Hello Canada</div>
<div class="hide US">Hello USA</div>
```

JS

```
$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    document.getElementsByClassName(response.country_code)[0].style.display = "block";
}, "jsonp");
```

CSS

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

Comment: please include your code in your answer, offsite only code based answers are not ok, please read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You successfully get the IP and country code. Now you just need to add an if statement to display the div's for the various countries. Just add

```
    var country = response.country_code;
    if(country == 'US' || country == 'CA') document.getElementById(country).style.display = "block";
```

inside your Get Request. You also need to have unique IDs so change your "Hello ____" code to

```
<div id="CA">Hello Canada</div>
<div id="US">Hello USA</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/1225/)**

Comment: I like how you changed your if condition to match my answer. :/

Comment: Yes I just made the change and was going to give credit to you. Your if statement is more efficient since it does not need multiple if/else if's

Comment: I'm just curious to why you don't use `{` and `}` I know it isn't a requirement but don't you find it better formatting? I know it's more of a personal preference but I'm just curious to why some people don't use them?

Comment: I like to keep my code as few lines as possible but keeping it readable. So, if my if statement is just 1 statement then I keep it all on one line. If its multiple statements i would put each statement on its own line.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Thank you :) I'm in the habit of adding `{` `}`

Comment: Some people also add their `{` on its own line, which I have never been a fan of because with proper indentation, I feel it's not needed.