# Jquery hide first, or second child element based on geoIP

Tags: jquery, geoip

I'd like to hide the the first div if the visitor is from the US and I'd like to hide the second div if the visitor is not from the US. Both div has the same class.

```html
<div class="myclass">from US</div>
<div class="myclass">not from US</div>
```

I've found some easy implementations with freegeoip.net/json, but I couldn't adapt them to my specific needs.

```js
$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response) {
$("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
document.getElementsByClassName(response.country_code)[0].style.display = "none";
}, "jsonp");
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? add some more examples code

Comment: I tried to adapt this example, but I failed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173809/how-to-show-or-hide-element-based-on-geo-ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you really need to do at this point is make an ajax call and read the response. Since you're using jQuery, this is relatively easy:

```
$.ajax('https://freegeoip.net/json/')
    .done(function (response) {
        var isUS = response.country_code === 'US';
        // Your code to hide/show here.
    });
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/ap3tfyf9/4/

I made a small change to the original code; the elements are hidden by default to avoid unwanted content.

Please note: For whatever reason, Firefox rejects the ajax call, but it works fine in Chrome. Because Firefox has additional, (occasionally unnecessary) security validations, this is likely due to something on the target server. I could not find an ip geolocation api that worked, but otherwise any other api would work the same way. Just check the response first to see how the country/country code is stored.

**EDIT**: Updated solution to target by position instead of class.

Comment: Thanks! I've got one issue with your solution, the divs are generated by complex php I don't want to modify and they have the same class names. I can't add classes to the divs, this is why I asked for a solution with first and second child.

Comment: Like I said, you can use Sergej's answer for that. I've updated my answer with a solution using that method to select the appropriate element. I've kept it hidden by default, but if you can't do that either, simply swap the numbers in the eq selector and change `.show()` to `.hide()`.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var isFromUS = true; // Get the flag from your geoIP service
        $('.myclass').eq(isFromUS ? 0 : 1).hide();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">from US</div>
<div class="myclass">not from US</div>
```

Comment: Have you read comments? The code just demonstates how to hide separate div element, base on a flag - is user from US or no. But not how to get user location. The flag can be get using geoIP service or HTML5 API (if end user allows it)

Comment: Thanks Sergej, this is what I was looking for, could you also add the code to retrieve the geoIP, something like ' "$.get("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (response)" '