# Dropdown and content change by country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown that changes the content according to the selected option (in this case 3 available countries) seen here:

```js
function hideAllContent(){
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementById('locations').children, function(v){
    v.style.display = 'none';
  })
}
function openCountry(divId){
  var el = document.getElementById(divId);
  if(el){
    hideAllContent();
    el.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.country {
  display: none;
}
.country:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="openCountry(value);">
  <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
  <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
  <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
</select>

<div id="locations">
  <div id="GT" class="country">
    Content for Guatemala
  </div>
  <div id="HN" class="country">
    Content for Honduras
  </div>
  <div id="SV" class="country">
    Content for El Salvador
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add automatic country detection so that the user's country is selected on the dropdown and the country div changes as well.
I was able to automatically change the dropdown by country with the assets in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sabahat88/pen/zNbPBv) but the div didn't change until the country was selected manually, plus freegeoip.net/json will soon be deprecated; ipinfo.io/json appears to do the same, [here's](https://codepen.io/miguelao/pen/QvyBPG) an example of that one, in case that helps.

I guess the javascript function should be called through something other than onchange to not only happen until manually changing the selection but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried to set the "selected" property for the OPTION that fits the current country? This should work as in the 1st codepen.

Comment: I wonder if starting with a `<option selected="selected" disabled="">Please Select</option>` as your first option will ensure that a change does indeed occur. I don't know where you are testing from - but if you're always getting Guatemala - then I don't think 'onchange' would fire.

Comment: I tried setting the first option as selected (I'm in El Salvador) and the dropdown changed to El Salvador without the content changing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173809/how-to-show-or-hide-element-based-on-geo-ip)… IF statements to display the content divs independent from the dropdown and another line for changing the dropdown.