# Hide mutliple elements based on Geo ip

Tags: jquery, html, css, geolocation

I've been implementing a tool to show hide elements (product prices) for users in different countries. e.g. UK users will see different prices to users from the US.

I have implemented a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173809/how-to-show-or-hide-element-based-on-geo-ip)

However, this only works for the first instance of the targeted heading which displays the price.

I know each id should be unique, but I don't know how to do this without duplicating the JQuery code for every product, is there an efficient method that can help me?

```js
    $.get("http://freegeoip.app/json/", function (response) {
      $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
                          

    $("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
                          

    if(response.country_code=='GB'||response.country_code=='US'){
                            

    document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
    }
    }, "jsonp");
```

```css
    #US { 
      text-align: left; 
      color: black; 
      display:none;
    }
 
    #GB { 
      text-align: left; 
      color: black; 
      display:none;
    } 
    
    
    #ip{
      display:none;
      color:white;
    }

    #country_code{
      display:none;
      color:white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ip">Loading...</div>
    <div id="country_code"></div>
    <div id="GB"><h4 class="h4black">£69.99</h4></div>
    <div id="US"><h4 class="h4black">$89.95</h4></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your `jQuery` working with the `class`-based approach explored below, swap this line:

```
document.getElementById(response.country_code).style.display = "block";
```

With this one:

```
$(`.${response.country_code}`).show();
```

If you're unable to use ES6 (or a newer standard) and thus, [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can use the older syntax:

```
$('.' + response.country_code).show();
```

---

A few points…

1. Use a `class` for the `HTML` elements housing the country codes, not an `id`. This will allow you to reveal multiple elements at once.
2. Since you're using `jQuery`, you might as well use the built-in functions it offers for the `DOM` lookups.

Here's an example demonstrating these points:

```js
$(".US").show();
```

```css
.US,
.GB {
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="GB">
  <h4 class="h4black">£69.99</h4>
</div>
<div class="US">
  <h4 class="h4black">$89.95</h4>
</div>
<div class="US">
  <h4 class="h4black">$89.95</h4>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/enmavtg5/1/)

Comment: How do i adjust my jQuery to accommodate for this?